# Reaction between elements in a periodic table

Tags: periodic-table, elements

Can we know the reaction between any two elements in the periodic table? If yes then can we know the reaction between any three or more elements in the periodic table?

Comment: Welcome to chemistry.SE! Um, I see problems in your question: 1. I really don't get what causes your question. What *is* confusing you? 2. If you're asking about "teach me chemical reactions" you must be asking something like "teach me all of chemistry."

Comment: Can you say more precisely, what are you asking? What do you mean by can we know? Reactivity of all relative stable elements is known.

Answer (score 4):

We don't even know completely the reaction of one element with itself.

For example, consider carbon.  There are constantly new forms of carbon being discovered.